# SSDT 2015 Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015, ssis, sql-server-data-tools, ssdt-bi

In Sql Server Data Tools 2015, i am able to create and execute SSIS packages. However when i try to deploy the projects containing SSIS packages, I get

> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

It works fine for other users on the system. It seems to be a user specific error. Any help is really appreciated. I need it to work with the said user only.

[image: Step1]

[image: Step 2]

Comment: Do you have script task (C# or VB.NET) anywhere in your code?